# UTC timestamp in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I have countdown plugin which takes a timestamp and returns a countdown in form of days / houers / minutes .... all my timestamps are stored in UTC timezone .

So this used to work fine until i've changed my website timezone .

I have to change my timezone  from time to time
... so now all the countdowns that i get are wrong .

This is how my plugin works basically

```
time_left_ms = given timestamp - currentstime stamp / 1000 ;
```

e.g

```
var time_left = Math.floor((options.timestamp - (new Date())) / 1000);
```

So i thought i can fix it using UTC timestamp like this

```
var d = new Date();
var utc =Date.UTC(d.getUTCFullYear(), d.getUTCMonth(), d.getUTCDate(), d.getUTCHours(), d.getUTCMinutes(), d.getUTCSeconds(), d.getUTCMilliseconds());

left = Math.floor((options.timestamp - (utc)) / 1000);
```

but still the same wrong result ...
after that i've tried this to see whats going on

```
console.log( d +'####'+utc +'####'+d.getTime());
```

and this is the output

```
Thu Sep 19 2013 19:10:13 GMT+0330 (Iran Standard Time)##1379605213010##1379605213010
```

whats wrong ? apparently time zone is on Asia/Thran ... but why do i get the same timestamp for Asia/tehran and UTC ? ... both are `1379605213010`

Comment: I believe time stamps are always UTC. The internal date representation is UTC.

Comment: What is wrong? What else did you expect? timestamps are universal, they have no timezone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dates are [specified](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.1) as the number of milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970 UTC:

> A Date object contains a Number indicating a particular instant in time to within a millisecond. Such a Number is called a time value. (...)
>
> Time is measured in ECMAScript in milliseconds since 01 January, 1970 UTC.

`Date.prototype.getTime` [returns this internal time value](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.9).

Answer (score 0):

This return UTC

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC

and This returns UTC

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime

It must be the same

I don't think there is a numeric representation of time for a time zone, it's always UTC

```
var x = new Date();
x.getTime();   //1379646809459
x.valueOf();   //1379646809459
```